# SQL error how to properly execute a query using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to execute a SQL query with a `GROUP BY` command but I cannot make it to work I tried to use a aggregate function to fix the problem but i think theres a better way to execute it correctly below is my SQL query.

```
SELECT TOP 100 cModel ,fdate, BoardSN 
FROM FovComp 
GROUP BY fdate ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime, fdate) DESC
```

The error is below

> Column 'FovComp.cModel' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I want to all columns but it must be group by `fdate` Any suggestion will be great.

Comment: The error is very clear, a quick search should allow you to solve it

Comment: First, please let everyone know what result / output you want to generate, then anyone can try to resolve your issue. Your question is not clear at all

Comment: So, there's going to be one row in the output for each unique value of `fdate`. Corresponding to those values, however, may be any number of distinct `cModel` and `BoardSN` values. How are *we*, or SQL Server, meant to know *which value* to pick from those to be represented in that single output row?

Comment: Group by is an unfortunate term aggregate by would be better.

Answer (score 2):

`GROUP BY` is useful for counting, summing or averaging, but you are doing none of that. And you *must* do it, otherwise `GROUP BY` makes no sense and is not allowed.

Example usage:

```
SELECT fdate, COUNT(cModel) AS COUNT_cModel, COUNT(BoardSN) AS COUNT_BoardSN
FROM FovComp 
GROUP BY fdate
ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime, fdate) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I want to COUNT cModel and `select all` columns and group it by` fdate`,

Comment: Please edit the question and add a representative set of input data (10-15 lines, with about 2-4 different `fdate` values) + your expected output for that set of data.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the latest data for each model, then you can use a ranking function do this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT cModel ,fdate, BoardSN,CONVERT(datetime, fdate) AS fdate,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cModel
                       ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime, fdate) DESC) AS RN
   FROM FovComp 
)
SELECT TOP 100 cModel ,fdate, BoardSN 
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY fdate DESC;
```

Also, If you are looking for the top 100 per each model, you can use `WHERE RN <= 100`

> I want to COUNT cModel and select all columns and group it by`fdate`, then you can do this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
      fdate,
      COUNT(cModel) AS ModelsCount
    FROM FovComp 
    GROUP BY fdate
)
SELECT f.*, c.ModelsCount
FROM FovComp AS f
INNER JOIN CTE AS c ON f.fdate = c.fdate ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 cModel ,fdate, BoardSN FROM FovComp ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime, fdate) DESC
```